# item tabulator same line

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, itemize

I want to put the item in the same line as the tab. Please have a look on my screenshot, how i actually want it to have.

```
\item Bewertung:

\begin{tabular}{l l c }
  & TestTest:  & Test \\
  & TestTestTest: & Test \\
  & TestTestTest: & Test \\
  & TestTestTestTest:  & Test\\
  & TestTestTest:  & Test\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why do you have this first `l` column if you are not putting anything in there?

Comment: @MaxNoe: Probably because he wants to add some horizontal space in front of the table. This can be achieved in better ways, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use newlines or a paragraph after `\item` and add the optional `[t]` argument to the `tabular` environment (`t` stands for `top` alignment)

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}

\item Bewertung: \begin{tabular}[t]{l l c }
  & TestTest:  & Test \\
  & TestTestTest: & Test \\
  & TestTestTest: & Test \\
  & TestTestTestTest:  & Test\\
  & TestTestTest:  & Test\\
\end{tabular}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not see the 3 in front of `Bewertung`. In this case, it should be an enumerate, of course

Comment: this does not work for me without the word "Bewertung:"

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Main text with paragraph indent. Now the list. Notice that the list labels
aligns with the left margin, the text and paragraphs thereafter with the paragraph indent

\begin{enumerate}[wide]
  \item Bewertung:
        %
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l l c }
            & TestTest: & Test \\
            & TestTestTest: & Test \\
            & TestTestTest: & Test \\
            & TestTestTestTest: & Test \\
            & TestTestTest: & Test
        \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `wide` option needed here?

Comment: That was because of the O.P.'s original condition (they seem to have been removed, but you can see them in the text above – which is not mine). Otherwise it's the same as your answer, so maybe I should delete it.

Comment: Nope, I would keep it. It's another way (you noticed the enumeration, I just missed it ;-))